# mysqli erroring with "commands out of sync" no matter how many times i call "next_result()"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been trying to get this php function to work for a while now but with no success. For some reason every time it runs i get a "commands out of sync, you cannot run this command now" error in my mysql. I am using the same techniques that i have been in every other php project that i have done, which is calling mysqli->next_result so that i can avoid that error. However, when i call it here it seems to have no effect.

```
if($questionType == 5){
    global $To;
        $to="znielsen@gbpi.net";
        $subject = "txtoutage session completed";
        $message ="Session completed by: ".$number." \n on: ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." \n";
        if($sid = $mysqli->query("CALL GetSessionFromPhoneNumProc('$number')")){
            $sids = $sid->fetch_assoc();
            $sid->free();
            $sids = $sids['sid'];
            $mysqli->close();
            $res->free();
            if($res = $mysqli->query("CALL GetAnswersFromSession('$sids')")){
                while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
                $mysqli->next_result();
                $qid = $row['Question_ID'];
                $question = $mysqli->query("SELECT Question_Text FROM questions WHERE Question_ID = '$qid'");
                $question = $question->fetch_assoc();
                $question = $question['Question_Text'];
                if($row['Answer_Text'] == null){
                    $displayText = $row['Answer_Body'];
                }
                else{
                    $displayText = $row['Answer_Text'];
                }
                $message = $message.$question.": ".$displayText." \n";
            }
        }
        else{
            $log->logError("mysql error sess: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error);
        }
    }
    else{
        $log->logError("mysql error answers: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error);
    }
    $from = "txtoutage@gbpi.net";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
```

Comment: You don't need `next_result` if you're not using `multi_query`. [Documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.next-result.php)

Comment: next_result has been working for every other query whenever it errors with "commands out of sync" is there a better way of avoiding this error?

Comment: Use it properly. Why are you even using `next_result`? Like I said, it's supposed to be used with `multi_query`. You only execute one query at a time, by using `query()`. You only need `fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: Do you have any other queries before this?  Any prepared queries?  If so, try to [`->close()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php) (or [`->free()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php)) them before this.

Comment: because i read in the documentation for mysqli that you have to use it between queries, when i don't use it i get commands out of sync.

Comment: when you say to use close() or free() you mean to the $mysqli variable correct?

Comment: No, actually.  [`free`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php) is used on the [result object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) (the object returned from [`query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)).  [`close`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php) is used on mysqli statements (the return value of [`prepare`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)).

Comment: its the get answers from session query that is erroring, i now have free called on $res, and close called on $mysqli. It still errors however.

Comment: Try calling `$sid->free()` after `$sid->fetch_assoc()`. (Change `$sid = $sid->fetch_assoc();` to another variable name).  My guess is the 2 `CALL`s are clashing with each other.

Comment: i just updated the code, it still errors the same way, correct me if i am wrong but i believe this is what you meant for me to change?

Comment: Lose the `$mysqli->close();`, that disconnects you from the database.  You're not using `$mysqli->prepare`, so you don't need to use `close`.  But, yes, I suggested adding `free`, but I'm not sure if it'll help.

Comment: Did I see 3 **nested loopes** each ***with a query?!***, something must be terribly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the call to `mysqli_next_result` from your code (this line: `$mysqli->next_result();`).

As explained in the PHP documentation, [mysqli_next_result](http://php.net/mysqli_next_result) prepares next result set from a previous call to mysqli_multi_query() which can be retrieved by mysqli_store_result() or mysqli_use_result().

Since you are not using `mysqli_multi_query()`, **you do not need and must not** call `mysqli_next_result`.

In your code, the next result is retrieved by using `mysqli_fetch_assoc`, and you are already using this function after each call to `mysqli_query`.